# Why calling external command returns 0 when done ok?

Tags: php, windows, system, command-line-interface

Example command:

```
echo "<pre>\n";
system('drush cc all', $retval);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Everything seems to be ok. There is a message that indicates command run correctly.

However $retval is always 0.

Comment: Because a successful executed program normally/traditionally return 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its return error code. There was no errors and you got 0.

Read about [Exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status).

Comment: For example EXIT_SUCCESS of C language has value 0